# Where is the mistake in my sqlite Table insert?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a little question..
The OperationalError is that table Roomname_long has no column named Number
but it has ??

```
def create_table_roomname_short():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Roomname_short ("Name" SHORT, "Number" NUM)')

def create_table_roomname_long():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Roomname_long ("GName" Gericht, "OName" Ort , "Number" NUM)')

def data_entry():
    short = "HH"
    num = 321
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Roomname_short (Name, Number) VALUES(?, ?)",
                                                  (short, num))
def data_entry_roomname_long():
    gericht = "Landgericht"
    ort = "Neuruppin"
    num = 4
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Roomname_long (GName, OName, Number) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
                                                  (gericht, ort, num))
    connect.commit()

create_table_roomname_short()
create_table_roomname_long()
data_entry()
data_entry_roomname_long()

c.close()
connect.close()
```

Comment: Are you maybe using an sqlite file that _doesn't_ have the column? You only create the table if it doesn't exist, and if it already did exist without the column, it won't have a column added.

Comment: the table roomname() has Number but now I want to add in table roomname_long() also Number .. @AKX

Comment: (1) There is no table `roomname` in your example. (2) Please show the code that establishes `c`. As my comment says, you're probably connecting to a database that already has an older version of `roomname_long` that doesn't have the column, and your `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` does not create the table since it already exists.

Comment: @AKX in first line there is table roomname.. if I commented out the second table roomname_long() it works but if I want to create the second one it crashes

Comment: No. In the second line of your post, you have a table called `roomname_short`. Not `roomname`.

Comment: @AKX sorry it has to be this way I forgot

Comment: I tried your code with a brand new database file, and it works fine. Please show us how you get `c` and `connect`, because **as I've said twice**, you're probably using a database file you've created earlier that doesn't have that column in the table, since **if I try your code with a brand new empty database file**, it works fine.

Comment: Oh it works.. how can I add something else in to it ?

Comment: You use [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) to add new columns to an existing table.

Answer (score 0):

To turn the comments to an answer:

You're seeing an issue since you're using a pre-existing database file in which the `Roomname_long` table exists, but doesn't have the `Number` column.

Since `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` does not create a table if it doesn't exist, or modify an existing table to match the new definition either, that's what you get.

Your options are to

- use a new database file (though this obviously is quite terrible if you already have data in it)
- use [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) to modify the existing table to add a new column if one doesn't exist (which is generally called schema migration).